# Files not correctly copying

Tags: mount, usb-drive, external-hdd

When trying to copy files from ubuntu to a partition on the hard drive or external hard drives the copy dialog finishes almost instantly. When the files are looked at via windows the files are empty. The files still appear to be opening correctly in ubuntu.

there were other questions asking about this but the responses didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Very strange. What kind of files? How do they "appear to be empty" in Windows? Do they have a file size in Windows? What about Ubuntu?

Comment: How are you copying them?

Comment: I've tried to copy them using copy and paste, but also using terminal. windows states they have a filesize but when right clicked they have a size of 0. The files are primarily pdf's but the issue occurs with all types.

Comment: Just checked, the files work as normal in my backtrack partition, so this appears to be a problem with windows reading the files ubuntu writes?